# xcode 4 stream video check

Tags: ios, xcode, url, stream, urlrequest

i am unable to solve this problem and i can´t find any solution elsewhere. I am playing the streaming video from url. But want to check if the url contains any video. Does anyone know how? To be clear i do not want to download the video and then play it. And yes i am checking the internet connection before, so i know if thre is internet or no. Is there any possible way how to check this? i just have URL with String ...i tried it with connection, but the page is connectablebut is blank with no content....:(

Thanks a lot for answer!=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your question didn't say what kind of video you're trying to view, but my guess for the reason the video is blank with no content would be because your iPhone (or simulator) doesn't know how to play video with the encoding that the page contains.

Also, what kind of URL are you using?  does it start with the standard `http://` scheme, or is it something else like `rtmp://` or `rtsp://` or `audio://` or?

If the URL starts with only `http://`, the only way that I can think of to check for a video stream is to download the html source from that page and scan through it looking for stream protocols (such as the ones I've listed above).

Comment: Hi problem solved I checked this in MPMoviePlayerViewDidLoad....I check the video status and that works great but I really appreciate Your suggestion. But I think if I would download the whole stream video which could have GBytes.... I will take some time and this is faster...=) but really thanks=)